# Jquery, Clear / Empty all contents of tbody element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I thought this would be rather simple but it seems the empty method is not working to clear out a tbody that I have. I would appreciate if anyone knows a proper way to do this, I just want to delete everything contained within the tbody. So far I am trying:

```
$("#tbodyid").empty();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody id="tbodyid">
<tr><td>something</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

NOTE: I am trying to do this to integrate with a plugin written by someone else that I am being made to use for a project. I am generating new `<tr><td>new data</td></tr>` server-side and want to just be able to wipe out the existing table rows and replace them on AJAX callbacks.

Comment: Have you tried the jsFiddle I just provided?

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will be trying it in a moment

Comment: Firefox... what did you try it in? I use Linux so I don't have IE installed, I suppose I could try it in Chrome but it needs to work in all of them anyways for this to work

Answer (score 166, accepted):

jQuery:

```js
$("#tbodyid").empty();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tbodyid">
        <tr>
            <td>something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Works for me** 
 http://jsfiddle.net/mbsh3/

Comment: I think chrome is more tolerant of some things like this than Firefox may be

Comment: Something is definitely wrong when you add a `thead` element. Firefox 78.0.2 http://jsfiddle.net/geLxhwsu/

Comment: The appending function was wrong. The syntax is `$('<tr>')` to create a new element and **not** `$('tr')`! Silly me http://jsfiddle.net/efmyp3s0/

Answer (score 62):

You probably have found this out already, but for someone stuck with this problem:

```
$("#tableId > tbody").html("");
```

Answer (score 14):

Example for Remove table header or table body with jquery

```js
function removeTableHeader(){
  $('#myTableId thead').empty();
}

function removeTableBody(){
    $('#myTableId tbody').empty();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTableId'  border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>1st heading</th>
    <th>2nd heading</th>
    <th>3rd heading</th>
  </thead>  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1st content</td>
      <td>1st content</td>
      <td>1st content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2nd content</td>
      <td>2nd content</td>
      <td>2nd content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3rd content</td>
      <td>3rd content</td>
      <td>3rd content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<form>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Table Header' onclick='removeTableHeader()'/>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Table Body' onclick='removeTableBody()'/>
</form>
```

Comment: $('#myTableId tbody').empty(); this is what i was looking for where I didn't wanted to put id for tbody element.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#tableId').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

This will not remove headers, it will clear only the table body.

Comment: Only this worked for me, I am using bootstrap 4 table

Answer (score 2):

```
        <table id="table_id" class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
             ...
             ...
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
```

use this command to clear the body of that table: `$("#table_id tbody").empty()`

I use jquery to load the table content dynamically, and use this command to clear the body when doing the refreshing.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `remove()` function of the example below
and build table again with table head, and table body

```
$("#table_id  thead").remove();
$("#table_id  tbody").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without use ID (`<tbody id="tbodyid">`) , it is a great way to cope with this issue

> $('#table1').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

PS:To remove specific row number as following example

> $('#table1 tr').eq(1).remove();

or

> $('#tr:nth-child(2)').remove();